# Display alert() click, relative to Id after .clone()

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, onclick

In this code, I can add other element. `Id` and `value` are changed after having generated.
I would like to display an alert when I click  on "**element3**" after an event clicks. I have already tried but it does not work.
In js/jquery code `$('#element3').click` doesn't work.

```js
    var current_num = 2;
    
    $('#element3').click(function(){
        alert("You did it, man!");
    })
    
    function addElement(){
        $("#element1").clone().appendTo("#elements").prop("id", "element"+current_num).attr("value", "element"+current_num) ;
        
        current_num++;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="elements">
  <input type="submit" id="element1" value="element1">
</div>
_____ <br> <br> <br>
<button onclick="addElement()" >Add</button>
```

Comment: because you bind the event before it exists

Comment: @Barmar not here.... needs more than that

Comment: Yeah, didn't read the question carefully enough. You beat me to it with the dupe.

Comment: `$(document).on('click', '#element3', function () {
   console.log('click');
});`

Comment: @epascarello , thanks dude ! you answered my question!